# Error -25294 when importing a distribution profile in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

I'm encountering an error in Xcode while trying to import a distribution profile. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
An error occurred. Unable to import "iPhone Distribution: Account (**********)". Error: -25294
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue, and I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve it. Can anyone help me understand what this error code means and how to troubleshoot it?

I suspect that this issue might be related to my recent action of resetting the default keychains in Keychain Access. Could resetting the default keychains be the cause of this error, and if so, how can I resolve it?

Is there anything else I should be looking into, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this specific error code (-25294) in this context?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add a distribution profile (I'm assuming this is a `.mobileprovision` file) into the Keychain. In order to use the profile using the Keychain, you should instead have/add the certificate associated with the profile and the private key associated with the certificate. As for the error, it indicates that the Keychain you're trying to insert the file into is missing or not present. Try adding it to the `login` Keychain instead and see what happens

Comment: Hi, I get this error when adding it to the 'login' keychain: `An error has occurred. Unable to import an item. The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.`

Comment: Try adding a new user on your MacBook (temporarily) and try to add the profile there. The login Keychain item can hardly be missing or not present. If that fails too, I believe the conclusion should be that a profile cannot be added to the Keychain. Can you comment on whether or not it's a provisioning profile you attempt to add?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I added a new user, and what do you mean by 'try to add the profile there'? Could you please clarify what profile you are referring to and where it should be added?

Comment: Oh, sorry. That might have been unclear indeed. The distribution profile you tried to add as mentioned in the question, what happens if you attempt to add that to the Keychain no the newly created user. Try adding the distribution profile to the `login` Keychain of the new user for instance

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but I don't know how to add that to the Keychain on the newly created user. How do I find the new user in the Keychain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255710/discussion-between-bram-and-my-car).